# continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with $dom(f) = [0, 1]$. Prove or refute the
following statements:

1. If $f(x_0) > 0$ for some $x_0 \in [0, 1]$, then there exists $\delta > 0$ for which $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $|x − x_0| < \delta$, i.e., $f$ is strictly positive on an interval containing $x_0$.
2. If $f(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in [0, 1]$ then there exists $\delta > 0$ for which $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $|x − x_0| < \delta$.

3.If f(q) = 0 for all rational numbers q ∈ Q ∩ [0, 1], then f(x) = 0 for all x ∈ [0, 1]

Comment: (a) Would you please use MathJax to format the math in the question? (b) What are your own thoughts on these questions?

Answer (score 1):

1. True. Indeed, suppose that $f(x_0) > 0$ for some $x_0 \in I = [0, 1]$ and take $\epsilon = f(x_0) > 0$. Using the continuity of $f$ on the unit interval, choose $\delta > 0 $ such that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ for $x \in B_{\delta} (x_0) \cap I$. In particular, $f(x) > f(x_0) - \epsilon = 0$ for $x \in B_{\delta} (x_0) \cap I$. This proves the claim.
2. False. For example, take $x_0 = 1/2$ and define $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x - \frac{1}{2}$. Then $f(1/2) = 0$, but $1/2$ is the only value $x$ in the domain with $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: for part 2, dom(F) is not [0,1] that should be all real. I think your example is worry.

Comment: If you want an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to the same effect then simply take $f(x) = x$.

Comment: If f(q) = 0 for all rational numbers q ∈ Q ∩ [0, 1], then f(x) = 0 for all x ∈ [0, 1]  how to prove

Comment: You'll need to post that as a separate question, hopefully with some context so that people can provide a good answer.